# WSO2 provides incorrect responses whith any reference element

Tags: wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to encode my own resource hierarchy in XACML based on the RBAC profile by Oasis using WSO2 identity server. However whenever I use  or  I get unexpected values.

This is a plolicySet with a reference to another policySet

```
        <PolicySet xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" PolicySetId="DPS4" Version="1.0">
       <Target>
          <AnyOf>
             <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Orders</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                </Match>
             </AllOf>
          </AnyOf>
       </Target>
       <PolicySetIdReference>PPS4</PolicySetIdReference>
    </PolicySet>
```

This is the referred PoilicySet, which refer to another Policy

```
    <PolicySet xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" PolicySetId="PPS4" Version="1.0">
   <Target/>
   <PolicyIdReference>PAP4</PolicyIdReference>
</PolicySet>
```

And this is the final Policy

```
    <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="PAP4" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <Target/>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="PermitOrders">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Match>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Emplyee</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
   </Rule>
</Policy>
```

The response should be Permit however I'm getting a Deny!!
Any suggestions?

Comment: This happen when I use <PolicySetIdReference> or <PolicyIdReference>  or adding reference to any element

Comment: The WSO2 implementation is quite buggy and partial...